# Angular2 XHR error(404 Not Found) while loading main.js

Tags: node.js, angular

I use gulp to watch typescript files and I store translated `.js` files in `public/js`. Whenever I start my project, angular2 doesn't work, because of this error:

> Cannot get main.js

[Here is the Error that I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5uhS.png)

system.config.js

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
paths: {
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
map: {
 app: 'public/js',

  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
},
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
});
})(this);
```

index.ejs

(I'm using express and all files below are loaded correctly).

```
<head>
  <title>Chat room</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">

  <script src="/systemjslib/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="/systemjsconf"></script>
  <script src="/shimlib/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/zonelib/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="/rxjslib/Reflect.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
</body>
```

main.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var platform_browser_dynamic_1 = require("@angular/platform-browser-dynamic");
var app_module_1 = require("./app.module");
platform_browser_dynamic_1.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(app_module_1.AppModule);
```

[Project files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bs2A.png)

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance. If I missed out some files that are important, let me know I will edit this post, I really need this fixed.

Comment: Are you sure your `.ts` files were compiled to `.js` files in the same location?

Comment: They don't have to all .ts files are translated and only .js files are being read. And yes , i've tried that sadly it doesn't work :(.

Comment: Please read my answer - are you sure you have a `main.js` there ?

Comment: Yes, i've included a link where you can see my folder structure.

Comment: What happens when you browse to localhost:3000/public/js/main.js ?

Comment: Cannot GET /public/js/main.js